# Feynman books analogous in chemistry

Tags: reference-request

Is there a analogous to feynman lectures in physics but for chemistry? Like a book ir series of books that covers all the basics?

Comment: I like Linus Pauling's General Chemistry. It is lucidly written. Unfortunately no Feynman equivalenr! Chemistry and chemical reactions do readily succumb to relatively simple mathematical models which are used in undergraduate physics. And most of the general chemistry taught these days is half early 20th century physics (atomic structure sections, gas laws, etc.).

Comment: @M.Farooq Actually everything you learn in undergrad chemistry is from the first half of the 20th century. :D

Comment: @Karl, The same goes for undergraduate physics and mathematics (BC to early 20 th century)

Comment: @M.Farooq In biology, it's a bit the other way round. Before Watson, Crick, and the electron microscope, they were stabbing in the dark, or satisfied with collecting stamps. ;) Figuratively speaking.

Comment: All the math I know is probably at least 150 years old.

Comment: Cannot agree more! Math is the oldest.